# iPad' Safari 10 doesn't load Angular 5 app (works on Safari 11)

Tags: angular, ipad, safari

I am deploying a SPA build with **Angular 5**. 
I tested on Windows **all latest** versions of browsers(ie, chrome, firefox, edge), and also on a Safari on Mac.

I cannot get it to work on **Safari 10**.

Below the debug message that I manage to extract when connecting iPad's Safari onto Mac's Safari Inspector. ⇓ ⇓ ⇓ ⇓

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great polyfill by nothing less than Mr Paul Irish, and it did the trick just fine. It's related over here, and I have to say it's a bit old, but nonetheless technically enough: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671

So just to be clear, I posted it on my index.html, as a essential script for loading on (*unfortunately*) every browser and etc.

```
(function() {

    var lastTime = 0;

    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];

    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {

        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];

        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] 

                                   || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];

    }



    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)

        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {

            var currTime = new Date().getTime();

            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));

            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 

              timeToCall);

            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;

            return id;

        };



    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)

        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {

            clearTimeout(id);

        };

}());
```

Comment: Anyone with more experience can confirm: is it better to leave this solution as an 'answer' to the question, or should I just 'update the question'?

Comment: I think it's fine to answer your own question like you did.  Thanks for coming back to update.